# Compilation has not happening in Blackberry Webwork

Tags: blackberry-webworks

Am very new to this Blackberry Webworks. My app not getting compile & also I can't able to get the signed .cod whenever I am using blackberry.advertising. [image]

For more ref: Here 's the error am getting, Please let me know any solution for this.

Thanks & Regards,
Krishnakumar P

Answer (score 0):

First thing I notice is you're running JDK 1.7 - You'll want to uninstall that, and install the 32Bit 1.6 JDK.

Secondly, if that doesn't help, are you using any extensions in your app?